# In PHP, Is "if($value)" the reciprocal of "if(empty($value))"?

Tags: php

In generating a `select` tag for a Boolean value, I use the following code:

```
<select name="name" id="id">
    <option value="0"<?php if(empty($value)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Off</option>
    <option value="1"<?php if($value): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>Off</option>
</select>
```

So, the question is, will this map correctly, so that at no point, both the options will have a `selected="selected"` property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only reason I see to use `empty()` here is to avoid warnings in case `$value` is not set. But in this case you get the warning next line. It's more common and prettier to use `!` to negate booleans otherwise.

But to answer your question, yes, your assumption is safe.

**Update**: The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) explicitly states that

> **empty()** is the opposite of *(boolean) var*, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set.

Comment: It's worth nothing that **!** and **empty** behave somewhat odd in the event you have a value = 0 as 0 == false.

Comment: cballou, PHP redefines meaning of "odd" when it comes to matters of Truth and Falsehood. Who would have guessed the outcome of *string* comparison `'0' == '0x0'` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`(bool) $value` is equivalent to `!empty($value)` and `!$value` is equivalent to `empty($value)`. See the [PHP type comparison tables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

eInteresting. Saying that:

- `$value`  *is the reciprocal of*  `empty($value)`

is, in my view, equivalent to asserting that

- `(bool) $value` *is equal to*  `!empty($value)`

In your example code `$value` is a bool, in which case the assertion is true (and Michael Krelin - hacker's answer that your assumption is safe is true).

But is this assertion is *generally* true? Considering the manual's documentation of `empty()`, I think it might be.

Comment: It *is*. The manual explicitly says "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set."

Comment: Well, that is, assuming that it is safe to make assumption regarding php ;-)

Comment: We'd be in trouble if we couldn't make _this_ sort of assumption about PHP, Michael :-)

Comment: fsb, we *are* in trouble when we're doing php.