# what 's the difference between empty($val) and !$val?

Tags: php

such as :

```
return empty(!$val);
```

and
    return !$val();

of  just make a boolean condition such as:

```
if (!empty($val)) {}
```

and

```
if ($val) {}
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of so many questions.

Comment: [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: Please make yourself with the basics of the PHP programming lanugage first, before asking a question. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [In PHP, Is “if($value)” the reciprocal of “if(empty($value))”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969131/in-php-is-ifvalue-the-reciprocal-of-ifemptyvalue) - Also please see [PHP: Empty() is the Opposite of a Boolean Variable](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/php-empty-is-the-opposite-of-a-boolean-variable/)

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual for empty](http://php.net/empty):

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. **empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.**

It avoids errors for cases such as `$_GET['foo']` where you cannot guarantee that the URL includes a `foo` query string parameter.

Answer (score 3):

PHP doc is very clear about that. There is nothing to add:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is
>   considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE.
>   empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

and

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ```
> "" (an empty string)
> 0 (0 as an integer)
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
> "0" (0 as a string)
> NULL
> FALSE
> array() (an empty array)
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

From the manual:

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

In other words, they're exactly the same other than empty not issuing a warning.